# Order by date in mysql

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I want to sort my result form mysql by date. I use the query like this:

```
<?php
$date = $db->get_query("select distinct created_date from comments");
$condate = '';
for($i=0; $i < count($date); $i++)
{
  $condate = $date[$i]['created_date'];
  $data = $db->get_query("select id,created_date from comments where created_date='$condate' order by created_date");
  ?>
  <table border='1' style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">
    <?php
    for($j=0; $j<count($data); $j++)
    {
      echo '<tr><td>';
      echo $data[$j]['id'] ;
      echo '</td><td>';
      echo $data[$j]['created_date'];
      echo '</td></tr>';
    }
    ?>
  </table>
<?php
}
?>
```

This query produce result like this:

```
2009-07-10 
2009-07-10
2009-08-21
2009-07-29
2009-08-15
```

The result is not sorted.
I want to see the result is:

```
2009-07-10
2009-07-10
2009-07-29
2009-08-15
2009-08-29
```

with separated table order by created-date.
I want to know sorting date in mysql result .In this case `$condate` is variable for validate condition.The value of `$condate` is all created_date in  comments table. I produce this as within loop and set the value is.
Please help me!

Comment: "where created_date='$condate'" - what is $condate in your query? I gess the reason is there.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only selecting results from a single date, then there's nothing to sort by. What exactly is the WHERE condition doing?

Edit: Now that you've posted your code, I can offer a suggestion. Your original code is running a separate query for each different date. What you really want is a single query that returns the results for *all* dates, but in a specific order, which is what the query in the code below does. Try this instead:

```
<?php     

    $data = $db->get_query("select id,created_date from comments order by created_date");
?>
<table border='1' style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">
   <?php


        for($j=0; $j<count($data); $j++)
        {

             echo '<tr><td>';
             echo $data[$j]['id'] ;
             echo '</td><td>';
             echo $data[$j]['created_date'];
             echo '</td></tr>';
        }

   ?>
</table>
```

Note that you already had all of this in your original code! You just managed to convince yourself that the task was more complicated than it actually was. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you put **=** in the where clause, so all the records will be in the same day and the sort will not be useful.

### Edit

Are you using **date** field type for created_date field or **string**? if it's string so that may cause your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have your date field is stored as a "string" and not something like datetime?

If you check with:

```
describe table_name;
```

How is your date stored?

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through results that aren't ordered to generate the dates you are asking for in the second query.  Up near the top you were querying:

```
$date = $db->get_query("select distinct created_date from comments");
// should be (and excuse the keyword capitalization, I just think its easier to read)
$date = $db->get_query("SELECT DISTINCT created_date FROM comments ORDER BY created_date");
```

You just put your `ORDER BY` clause on the wrong query.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to execute 2 queries.
Try executing 
$data = $db->get_query("select DISTINCT id,created_date from comments where created_date='$condate' order by created_date");
I think you had all built-in in your code but you just got confused a little.

Do let me know whether this solved your problem or not.